# How to make height NSPopupButton to fit for item automatically

Tags: cocoa, nspopupbutton

Please have a look at the picture, sometimes when pull down the button, the last item will only display half height. Anyone know how to make it to show full.[image]

For example, only show the "egg" and then the arrow; or show full height of the last item "from".